# TSQL Looking for a way to add a incrementing id based on cell result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to set an id that increments based on the cell results like below in SQL Server.

```
ID, Name, Address
1,John,123 Main
2,John,345 My St
3,John,768 Any Rd
1,Bob,143 Main
2,Bob, 386 My St
3,Bob, 765 Any Rd
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are looking for a [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Query can be like

```
select row_number() over(partition by name order by address asc) as id,*
from yourtable
```